# Open Source Actionscript 3 or Javascript date utility classes?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I was wondering if anyone could point to an Open Source date utility class that is fairly robust. I find myself rolling my own when I want to do a lot of things I take for granted in C# and Java. For instance I did find a decent example of a DateDiff() function that I tore apart and another DatePart() function. Another examples would be parsing different date/time formats. I'm trying to avoid reinventing something if it's already built.

Another possibility may be a nice set of Javascript files that I can convert to ActionScript 3. So far I've found [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com) but I want to get a good idea of what is out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) has the [DateUtil](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/blob/master/src/com/adobe/utils/DateUtil.as) class and it should be pretty reliable since it's written by some Adobe employees. I haven't encountered any problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [DP_DateExtensions](http://www.depressedpress.com/Content/Development/JavaScript/Extensions/DP_DateExtensions/Index.cfm), though I believe DateJS is more robust.